# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning ignoring unexpected dylib file

Tags: ios, xcode, ld, dylib, mach-o

I'm trying to build a framework(Valid Architectures in my settings are arm64, armv7, armv7s, $(ARCHS_STANDARD), i386) and my Xcode project is throwing out these warnings at me. The project builds successfully but I want to get these resolved. If someone can at least guide me what are the reasons for these warnings, I will try to get them resolved.

THis is what Xcode have passed for the Ld

```
Ld /Users/panisetty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABDWorkspace-dzxyvnbxeuwterbtlrwhpsjsxrwm/Build/Intermediates/ABD.build/Debug-iphoneos/ABDDistCoreFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ABDDistCoreFramework normal armv7
    cd /Users/panisetty/Documents/Code/Stash/CoreWorkspace/ABD
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -r -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/panisetty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABDWorkspace-dzxyvnbxeuwterbtlrwhpsjsxrwm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/panisetty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABDWorkspace-dzxyvnbxeuwterbtlrwhpsjsxrwm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/panisetty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABDWorkspace-bbwocslpbrwjhbfdlqwaweghxrof/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/panisetty/Documents/Code/Stash/CoreWorkspace/ABD -F/Users/panisetty/Documents/Code/Stash/CoreWorkspace/ABD/CoreFramework/StoreLocator -filelist /Users/panisetty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABDWorkspace-dzxyvnbxeuwterbtlrwhpsjsxrwm/Build/Intermediates/ABD.build/Debug-iphoneos/ABDDistCoreFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ABDDistCoreFramework.LinkFileList -nostdlib -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework GLKit -framework Security -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreData -framework AVFoundation -framework GoogleMaps -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreText -framework CoreFoundation -framework OpenGLES -framework ImageIO -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/panisetty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABDWorkspace-dzxyvnbxeuwterbtlrwhpsjsxrwm/Build/Intermediates/ABD.build/Debug-iphoneos/ABDDistCoreFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ABDDistCoreFramework_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/panisetty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABDWorkspace-dzxyvnbxeuwterbtlrwhpsjsxrwm/Build/Intermediates/ABD.build/Debug-iphoneos/ABDDistCoreFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ABDDistCoreFramework




ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//GLKit.framework/GLKit, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreData.framework/CoreData, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreText.framework/CoreText, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES, ignoring unexpected dylib file
    ld: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//ImageIO.framework/ImageIO, ignoring unexpected dylib file
```

Comment: As the error says,the linker could not find the frameworks, link the frameworks in Build Phases -> Link Binary with libraries in Xcode project settings.

Comment: @k6sandeep I have linked all the libraries. It is not a error warning. Which says "ignoring unexpected dylib file" for all the frameworks that I linked in "Link Binary With Libraries" section

Comment: The double slashes are a hint. Post the portion of your build log that shows what was passed to the linker.

Comment: @quellish I have updated the question with the commands passed to linker. I appreciate your time in looking into this. :)

Comment: @quellish I have changed my Mach-O Type to "static Library" and all the warning went away. I'm trying to build a framework. Can I use this setting ?

Comment: @Priyatham51, the linker is ignoring those frameworks because it thinks it does not need them or cannot use them. This would happen, for instance, if you were linking an armv7 binary but it was attempting to link against i386 frameworks (which is not the case here, from what you posted). If you are importing those frameworks as modules as well that may be the problem

Comment: @quellish Why did scode stop throwing error when I changed my Mach-O Type to Static Library.

Comment: @Priyatham51 I can't tell from the information you have provided. A static library target would still be able to link against dynamic system frameworks, and your linker arguments are specifying that. If those frameworks were themselves *static frameworks* and you were building a dynamic framework, that may cause the symptoms you're seeing - but that should not be the case here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68449/discussion-between-priyatham51-and-quellish).